# Error when trying to call javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

I'm trying to add a listener into the 'Yes' button which is shown in the code below.I want this function to save this boolean value into `approval` field in my database like:$query_row['approval']==1;  and a message to display on it.But when executing the code nothing happens after  clicking on the'Yes button'.
Can someone please show me how to fix this code if there is an error on it?
Thanks in advance!

This is my code:

```html
<html >
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>




<?php



if( !($database=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))||!(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database))  )
   print("Could not connect");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `admin` = 0  AND  `approval`=0");
  // if($_POST['admin']==0) {//perjashton administratorin
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {//esht aprovuar llogaria
      if(!($result=mysql_query($query,$database)))
{
    print("Could not execute query");
    die (mysql_error());//ose error
}
//nese  esht aprovuar logini i st.

echo "You are approved";
}
else //approval=0
echo"YOU HAVE NEW REQUESTS WAITING FOR APPROVAL IN YOUR WEBSITE!!!<br />";
while($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $firstname=$query_row['firstname'];
$lastname=$query_row['lastname'];
$username=$query_row['username'];
$password=$query_row['password'];
$email=$query_row['email'];
$cv=$query_row['cv'];
echo $firstname.'   '.$lastname.'  has this cv:'.$cv.'<br /> Do you want to approve his account?
<button id="but">Yes</button><button>No</button><br />
<p id="demo"></p>';
?>
<script>
document.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click", MyFunction());

function MyFunction() {
  $query_row['approval']==1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "This account is approved";}

    </script>
<?php
}mysql_close($database);
?>



</body>
</html>
```

And this is my database with the `approval field` which boolean value I'm trying to change:[image: Theb database]

Comment: Please explain details about what you want to do in this file.

Answer (score 0):

Change `document...addEventListener("click", MyFunction());` to `document...addEventListener("click", MyFunction);` otherwise your function executes immediately and only once.

Comment: Still the same output.Nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, if you expect a value in database to update, this won't happen just with `$query_row['approval']==1;` inside your `MyFunction`. Actually you should remove it from your script because it should cause an error in javascript. And you will have to send this information to server explicitly, best with ajax request as @Luka wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a value in the database only with changing value of the output array. You have to create a new php file and call it asynchronuslly. Read more about updating values in the database [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) and about calling files asynchronuslly [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).

First, I will edit your main file because it's a mess (sorry to say that, but don't worry, it was same with me):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
function MyFunction(id) {
  var xhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      if(xhttp.responseText.indexOf("UPDATE WENT OK")!=-1)
        document.getElementById(id).nextSibling.innerHTML = "This account is approved";
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById(id).nextSibling.innerHTML = "An error occured while approving this account";
      }
    }
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_file.php?id="+id, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if(!($database = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")) || !(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database)))
   print("Could not connect");
else {
  $result = mysql_query($database,"SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `admin` = 0  AND `approval`=0");
  if(!$result){
    print("Could not execute query");
    die (mysql_error());//ose error
  }
  else{
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {//esht aprovuar llogaria
      //nese  esht aprovuar logini i st.
      echo "You are approved";
   }
    else {               //approval=0
      echo"YOU HAVE NEW REQUESTS WAITING FOR APPROVAL IN YOUR WEBSITE!!!<br/>";
      while($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $firstname=$query_row['firstname'];
        $lastname=$query_row['lastname'];
        $username=$query_row['username'];
        $password=$query_row['password'];
        $email=$query_row['email'];
        $cv=$query_row['cv'];
        echo $firstname.'   '.$lastname.'  has this cv:'.$cv.'<br /> Do you want to approve his account?';
        ?><div class="container"><button id="<?php echo $query_row['id'];?>" onclick="MyFunction(this.id)">Yes</button><button>No</button><br />
        <p class="demo"></p></div><?php
      }
    }
  }
}
mysql_close($database);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, create a php file named ajax_file.php (in the same folder):

```
<?php

if(!($database = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")) || !(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database)))
   die("Could not connect");
else {
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$result = mysql_query($database,"UPDATE table `login` SET approval = 1 WHERE `id` = '".$id."'");
if(!$result){
  print("Could not execute query");
  die (mysql_error());//ose error
}
else{
  echo "UPDATE WENT OK";
}
```

Do not hesitate to ask me about any detail how this works. Also, this might not be correct because i don't exactly know what you are doing or want to do with the file you provided. But, if you'll give me the details, I will edit it so it will work.